# How to escape the endless ocean in "Way of the Nether"?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In the new Nether Update there is a free marketplace map called *Way of the Nether.*  When the other player died in the Nether I was still in the Overworld and somehow I got transported to an apparently endless ocean. **How do I escape this and find my way back to land?**  I have tried swimming for some time but it is just ocean in every direction and I don't even know which way is land.

Comment: Can you clarify what this game; "Way of the Nether" is? I ask this because there's no official game from Mojang called that.

Comment: @BlueTangsRock Apparently it's a free item in the marketplace that is available with the new Nether Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a single island in the Overworld; the ocean stretches out on all sides of it.  You can't really watch which direction the clouds are moving, because they move too slow to make out while swimming, and you'll drown if you try to watch them from the bottom of the ocean long enough.  Even if you could tell which direction they were moving, this wouldn't tell you which way the island was.  If you didn't happen to have a compass or map (which it's likely you don't), you'll either have to swim around in a spiral hoping to hit land and hope that everyone else will finish the quest and/or be able to switch into creative mode.  Otherwise, try drowning and see if you respawn in the village.

Comment: Did you have coordinates enabled on the world? Prehaps you could get someone to join the world in the intended location, have them tell you the coordinates, and try to move over to there. Even though most map worlds don't have coordinates enabled by default, you could change it in the world options before you join the world.

Comment: @BlueTangsRock No, unfortunately, and they were too busy killing mobs in the Nether to come help me :D

Answer (score 0):

That is strange.
I have played this map before and never encountered this. Maybe a multiplayer issue?
Whatever the reason, the easiest way out would just be to use a command to teleport to your friend. (Cheating, I know, but achievements were disabled anyway.)